# REST Controller not working unless F12 is pressed

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

I was wondering on why I am receiving this exception in the Eclipse IDE when I press a button which will fire the AJAX event:

> Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException

However, if I press F12 in Chrome the program will work. I am using Spring Boot while passing the AJAX request to the REST Controller.

```java
public ResponseEntity<?> readData(@RequestBody String string){
  System.out.print(string);
  FileProcessor fileProcessor = new FileProcessor();
  fileProcessor.execute(string.split("\n"));
  List<Record> records = fileProcessor.getRecords();
  return new ResponseEntity<List<Record>>(records,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

```js
    var ajaxRead = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        ajaxRead = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        ajaxRead = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if(ajaxRead) {
    ajaxRead.open("POST","/readFile",true);
    ajaxRead.send(verify + "\n" + data);
    ajaxRead.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRead.readyState === 4){
            if(ajaxRead.status === 200){
                 alert("Success!");
            }else
                clearFile(ajaxRead.responseText);
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Unfortunately, there is not enough information in your question to be able to answer it.  Do you have Developer tools open when you make the AJAX call? (F12 would close it) If so, do you have a breakpoint in the JS file ? it's the only thing that comes to mind

Comment: Yes, when I open Developer tools it works. I removed all the debuggers already. But when Developer tools is not open, it sends the exception to Eclipse. I am using AngularJS as the front end*

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"Eclipse in Google Chrome"_? Do you perhaps have a browser extension that's hooked in to the Eclipse debugger?

Comment: No, it sent the exception to the Eclipse IDE

Comment: Do you have any browser extensions installed that may be halting the POST request? Try in an Incognito window or another browser

Comment: I tried IE and it worked when I press the button 2 or 3 times (with or without F12). The incognito has a similar result

Comment: What `data` that you sending on POST request? and what is the main job of `FileProcessor` on Java class?

Comment: I used a FileReader to read the data of the file and pass the data to the AJAX request with the type of file extension

Comment: The FileProcessor will send a request to the db and return a list of records